# Python 2.7.8 expected an indented block help please

Tags: python

Hey guys so when i added the while true statement it started giving me

> IndentationError: expected an indented block

Any of you guys know how to fix its bothering me :/

```
import urllib
import urllib2

count = 0
while True:

var = raw_input("Please enter a username: ")

print "you entered", var
print "now starting"

headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0',

'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',

'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
}

url = "http://example.com"

params = urllib.urlencode({'strUsername': var})

req = urllib2.Request(url, params)

count  + 1

req.addheaders = [(headers)]

page = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()

if page.find("success"):
    print "Username Checked:", var, count
```

Comment: Please add spaces for your code lines so it is shown as code.

Comment: Ah alright sorry i was wondering why it wouldn't show lulz

Comment: @Reptic: `count + 1` is not what you want. You'll want `count = count + 1` or `count += 1`. (And please stop using street slang here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indent  your code inside the `while loop`, you have to have at least the first line indented after a `while loop`.

```
while True:    
    var = raw_input("Please enter a username: ")    
    print "you entered", var
    print "now starting
    # all code that needs to be in the loop goes here

# code here at this level is outside your loop
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means exactly what it says.

In Python, indentation is significant. The way Python knows what statements are controlled by that `while True:` is because they're indented one step further to the right than the `while True:`. For example, this:

```
while True:
    print('still going')
    print('and going')
print('done')
```

… will print `still going` and `and going` over and over and over, and never print `done`, because the first two statements are part of the `while` loop (because they're indented), and the third is not (because it's dedented back to the margin).

So, you have to take all the code you want to be inside the loop and move it 4 spaces to the right.